# Accidentally installed the Matlab launcher without the actual Matlab and cannot stop the installation process

Tags: launcher, uninstall, matlab

I do not have Matlab in my computer so the installer keeps on asking me where is Matlab located and I do not know how to make it stop asking! Tried uninstalling the launcher in terminal with

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab
```

but I get the error

```
Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/),is another process using it?
```

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/),is another process using it?
```

The error means that there is already another process running, thats why you can't uninstall it.
Make sure all other instances of apt-get are closed then you should be able to uninstall it.